# LG optimus 4x HD root

Tags: rooting, lg-optimus-4x

I tried to root my phone, but got only to the step 10, because my phone is too damn slow! I can't do anything with my phone, all I'm able to do is restart it over and over again, I can't even go to the lock screen. Can someone please help me? Is there a way to get my phone back to how it was? I don't need the root.

Link to the site I used while trying to root my phone:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=29868577

The rooting steps were posted by alexp999.

Comment: Is it **ICS** or **JB**? That method does not work for JB+ . See [comment](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1818502&page=37#post39933914)

Comment: To undo steps 1-9, you might try to boot into [safe mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) and remove the *SystemBackupTest* app. After the next reboot, your phone should be "back to normal", hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reinstall your firmware using [this](http://www.lg.com/uk/support-mobile/lg-P880) tool. It's the official update tool for lg phones. After that you can just root your phone again. Just remember, it's almost impossible to completely ruin your phone ;)

Edit: You might want to make a backup, because during the update you lose everything on your **internal sd** (everything on your external sd is safe)